# How can I display form instance?

Tags: python, django

How can I pass the form with an actual filled profile informations (like ProfileUpdateForm(instance=x) in function views).
I did it this way and have no idea how to pass an actual profile instance to the form. Something like UpdateView, but in my DetailView class

```
 class ProfileDetailView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Profile
    context_object_name = 'profile'
    template_name = 'profiles/myprofile.html'
    form_class = ProfileUpdateForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
    
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('profiles:profile', kwargs={'pk': self.get_object().pk})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update an instance of a model you should use [`UpdateView` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview):

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView

class ProfileDetailView(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    context_object_name = 'profile'
    template_name = 'profiles/myprofile.html'
    form_class = ProfileUpdateForm
        
    def get_success_url(self):
        # Use `reverse` instead of `reverse_lazy`. You will get an error otherwise!
        return reverse('profiles:profile', kwargs={'pk': self.get_object().pk})
```

Also if there is any need to pass a keyword argument to the form (here `instance`, although I would suggest to stick with `UpdateView`) you should override `get_form_kwargs`:

```
class MyView(SomeGenericView):
    ...
    
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['some_kwarg'] = 'Some value'
        # Your use case implies below line
        # kwargs['instance'] = self.get_object()
        return kwargs
```

Comment: Yeah, but I want it to be in my DetailView, is this even possible to accessing same template with two different views?

Comment: @adrq `UpdateView` inherits from `SingleObjectMixin` down the line, which is the most basic building block of `DetailView`. So you can expect to have a variable named `profile` in your context with `UpdateView` also.

Comment: I dont understand, so what I have to do with my urls when i have two different views accessing same template? code: path('<int:pk>/', views.ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name='profile')

Comment: @adrq what I mean is **don't** use `DetailView` for this purpose. Use `UpdateView` instead of that. Also check my edit if you really want to know how to pass keyword arguments to the form. Also why do you use `reverse_lazy` in `get_success_url`? You should be using `reverse`.